# Auxiliary Database Objects with Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I know it's possible to run extra DDL scripts with NHibernate. For example triggers or indexes. This feature is NHibernate is named "[Auxiliary Database Objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-database-object)".

Is it possible to do same thing in Castle ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchemaFromFile("myscript1.sql");
```

(from http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/schemagen.html)

Comment: I'm currently generating database schema based on classes. "myscript1.sql" must be run as complementary. It seems to me that `CreateSchemaFromFile` prevents tables to be created from classes.

Comment: @afsharm: I'm pretty sure you can run both.

Comment: It does not work. calling `CreateSchemaFromFile` does not do any operation.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Diego said, `ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchemaFromFile` is the way to do this.

If it doesn't execute anything, make sure your SQL script has its lines separated by `;` (or `GO`). Even if you have a single line in your file, it has to end with `;`

Comment: I added ; and go at end of lines and end of scripts files. But still nothing works. I used SQL Profiler but nothing is sent to database.